# Error while compiling Open Frameworks on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: openframeworks

I am trying to compile OF on Ubuntu 18.04. I installed the dependencies without any problem. The issue seems to come from glew.h and glext.h :

```
makefileCommon/compile.core.mk:238: recipe for target '/home/XXX/Téléchargements/of_v0.10.1_linux64gcc6_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/obj/Debug/libs/openFrameworks/3d/of3dPrimitives.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/XXX/Téléchargements/of_v0.10.1_linux64gcc6_release/libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/linux64/obj/Debug/libs/openFrameworks/3d/of3dPrimitives.o] Error 1
makefileCommon/compile.core.mk:212: recipe for target 'Debug' failed
make: *** [Debug] Error 2
there has been a problem compiling Debug OF library
please report this problem in the forums
```

And I have a lot of error like that :

```
In file included from /home/XXX/Téléchargements/of_v0.10.1_linux64gcc6_release/libs/openFrameworks/utils/ofConstants.h:212:0,
             from /home/XXX/Téléchargements/of_v0.10.1_linux64gcc6_release/libs/openFrameworks/3d/ofMesh.h:6,
             from /home/XXX/Téléchargements/of_v0.10.1_linux64gcc6_release/libs/openFrameworks/3d/of3dPrimitives.h:3,
             from /home/XXX/Téléchargements/of_v0.10.1_linux64gcc6_release/libs/openFrameworks/3d/of3dPrimitives.cpp:9:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:12099:90: error: 'void __glewGetFragmentMaterialivSGIX(GLenum, GLenum, GLint*)' redeclared as different kind of symbol
 GLAPI void APIENTRY glGetFragmentMaterialivSGIX (GLenum face, GLenum pname, GLint *params);

In file included from /home/XXX/Téléchargements/of_v0.10.1_linux64gcc6_release/libs/openFrameworks/utils/ofConstants.h:210:0,
             from /home/XXX/Téléchargements/of_v0.10.1_linux64gcc6_release/libs/openFrameworks/3d/ofMesh.h:6,
             from /home/XXX/Téléchargements/of_v0.10.1_linux64gcc6_release/libs/openFrameworks/3d/of3dPrimitives.h:3,
             from /home/XXX/Téléchargements/of_v0.10.1_linux64gcc6_release/libs/openFrameworks/3d/of3dPrimitives.cpp:9:
/usr/include/GL/glew.h:19357:52: note: previous declaration 'void (* __glewGetFragmentMaterialivSGIX)(GLenum, GLenum, const GLint*)'
 GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLGETFRAGMENTMATERIALIVSGIXPROC __glewGetFragmentMaterialivSGIX;
```

I didn't touch those files so please share your ideas on why the compilation fails !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer on the OF forum, here's the [link](https://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/cannot-compile-of-errors-on-of3dprimitives-and-conflicting-gl-glew-declarations/30307). I leave the post here in case you have the same issue.